# DataGrid columns auto width

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I set up `DataGrid` where should all columns excepts one have size by its content. So I set these columns to `auto` and the other one to `*`. But DataGrid ignores it and content in column with header `Množ` is not completely visible.

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" Margin="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RadkyDokladu.radky}" CanUserSortColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="12" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding ZASKRTNUTO}" Width="auto" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Náz" Binding="{Binding Artikl_NAME}" MinWidth="10" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Místo" Binding="{Binding Umisteni_NAME}" Width="auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Množ" Binding="{Binding Mnozstvi, StringFormat=F2}" Width="auto">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MJ" Binding="{Binding Jednotka}"  Width="auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Image after run:
[image]

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: It *might* have something to do with the format statement. Perhaps the width of the text is determined *before* the formatting is applied.

Comment: Thanks for comment, ff this will be the reason, is here any way how to go around?

Comment: I don't know for sure that that's the reason. Try removing the formatting and include a value with a decimal (e.g. 2.45) and see if it gets the width correct in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the size of your `DataGrid`. By setting:

```
<DataGrid Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ...
```

your `DataGrid` size belongs to the width of the `TreeViews` parent (window). You could try activating `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` to stretch the `DataGrids` contents and scroll inside your `DataGrid`.

A second approach is to drop `Margin`, that the `DataGrid` can expand depending on contents.